# Problem returning field in ms sql 2005 - System.InvalidCastException:

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the code below, I am returning an nvarchar field from *MS SQL 2005* and keep getting a System.InvalidCastException.

```
vo.PlacementID = dr.IsDBNull(0) ? null : dr.GetString(0);
```

The vo.PlacementID variable is of type String so there shouldn't be a problem.
The values I am trying to return are like this (number, number, letter): 00F, 02A, 01F, etc

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to 
type 'System.String'.
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the exception again it gives you a clue as to the problem:

> System.**InvalidCastException**:
>   ***Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type
>   'System.String'***. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32
>   i)

Basically the underlying data type being returned in column 0 of your SqlDataReader isn't a string compatible type, hence the cast exception.

I'd suggest setting a breakpoint on the offending line and then execute the following line in the immediate window:

```
? dr.GetValue(0).GetType()
```

This will tell what type being returned.

Answer (score 1):

the cast exception is not raised in the assignment, but in the datareader's GetString().

try dr.GetValue(0).ToString()

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidCastException` isn't raised because of the type incompatibility between the `PlacementID` property and `string`. If that was the case, you'd get a compile-time error. The problem is the first field in the result set is not a `string`, it's something else.